# MKMapItem recognized in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, mkmapitem

So I'm using NSClassFromString to check if the user has iOS 5 or iOS 6 installed to use Apple's new iOS 6 MKMapItem.  This is the code:

```
- (void)openDirections:(id)sender {
    Class mapClass = NSClassFromString(@"MKMapItem"); 

    if (mapClass == nil) {
    // iOS 5, do something here
    }
    else {
    // iOS 6, open up maps with MKMapItem.
    }
}
```

By the code above, when I run it on iOS 5.1 simulator or a iOS 5.1 device, the iOS 6 branch gets run.  However, if I use

```
Class mapClass = NSClassFromString(@"PKPass");
```

which was also introduced in iOS 6, my code follows the appropriate iOS 5 or iOS 6 branch.  Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MKMapItem` exists in prior versions of iOS because it was in development then, therefore the class existed. Instead, Apple recommends that you should use the following code also checking for a method they specifically added in iOS 6.0:

```
Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
   // Use class
}
```

Information from [MKMapItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html)